# Stepper motor doesn't start immediately when i pressed the button

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, arduino-motor-shield

When I release my hand from the button on pin 2, the stepper motor takes at least few seconds to stop, but I want it stop immediately. here's my codes:

```c
 #include <Stepper.h>

    const int stepsPerRevolution = 200;  // change this to fit the number of steps per revolution
    // for your motor

    // initialize the stepper library on pins 8 through 11:
    Stepper myStepper(stepsPerRevolution, 8, 9, 10, 11);

    bool dir = false;
    bool power = true;

    void dir_pin() {
      if (!digitalRead(3)) {
        dir = !dir;
      }
    }//when the switch is being pressed
    //it condition would be different from last time

    void setup() {
      // set the speed at 60 rpm:
      myStepper.setSpeed(60);
      // initialize the serial port:
      Serial.begin(9600);
      pinMode(2, INPUT_PULLUP);//it is a easier way to using INPUT-PULLUP
      //cause you dont have to use a real resistor
      pinMode(3, INPUT_PULLUP);//why choose those two pins
      //cause for uno, the interrupt pin are pin 2 and pin 3
      attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(3), dir_pin, FALLING);
      pinMode(A0, INPUT);
    }

    void loop() {
      int pwr = analogRead(A0) / 100;
      Serial.print("power:");
      Serial.print(power);
      Serial.print("  pwr:");
      Serial.print(pwr);
      Serial.print("  dir:");
      Serial.println(dir);
      while (digitalRead(2) == 0)
      {
        if (pwr) {
          myStepper.setSpeed(pwr);
          int pwr = analogRead(A0) / 100;

          if (dir) {
            //Serial.println("clockwise");
            myStepper.step(stepsPerRevolution);
            //delay(500);
          }
          // step one revolution in the other direction:
          else if (!dir) {
            //Serial.println("counterclockwise");
            myStepper.step(-stepsPerRevolution);
            //delay(500);
          }
        }
        else
        {
          myStepper.step(0);
        }
      }
      while (digitalRead(2) == 1)
      {
        pwr = 0;
        myStepper.step(0);
      }
      delay(10);
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't start immediately? (as in the title?) or Doesn't stop immediately? (as in the body?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tell it to move whole 200-step revolutions, so once it begins a revolution, it must continue.  At 60 RPM, that should be up to 1 full second after you open pin 2.   Depending on the analogRead(A0)/100, a full revolution could take much longer than 1 second -- maybe 5.86s to 6000s

If you want it to stop immediately, disregarding full revolutions, you could:

```
      stepsPerButtonpress = 1;

      ...

      if (dir) {
        //Serial.println("clockwise");
        myStepper.step(stepsPerButtonpress);
        //delay(500);
      }
      // step one revolution in the other direction:
      else if (!dir) {
        //Serial.println("counterclockwise");
        myStepper.step(-stepsPerButtonpress);
        //delay(500);
      }
```

Or you could reduce stepsPerRevolution to the fraction of steps you want to treat as a unit, and increase rpm proportionally.